# php json encode outputting invalid json from mysql results

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [encode json using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531965/encode-json-using-php)

```
$hello_world = $this->session->all_userdata();
foreach($hello_world as $key=>$product_id)
{
$query['products']  = $this->Global_products->globalFindProductsViewed($product_id);
    foreach($query['products'] as $product)
{
$ryan[] = $product->name;
}

}
foreach($ryan as $r) 
{
    echo json_encode(array($r));
}
```

The output then looks like this:
["Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck"]

I know I cant access this with JavaScript.
Can someone suggest how I can make this work?

Comment: The output looks fine to me. What do you believe the problem is?

Comment: I think I will have a problem accessing it via ajax

Comment: You *think*? Have you even *tried*?

Comment: No because I know that in order to access the data it has to be in a certain format.

Comment: Like this format: [{"hello":"Rand McNally Soft Case for Most 5\" GPS"},{"hello":"Rand McNally Hard Case for Most 5\" GPS"}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3752/discussion-between-rpm-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams)

Comment: `js> eval('["Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck"]')[0]`
`Alpine 50W x 4 Apple® iPod®-Ready In-Dash CD Deck`
(but don't actually use `eval()` to parse your JSON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON encoding every array element separately doesn't make sense.

Remove the foreach, and just do a

```
echo json_encode($ryan);
```