# Respond with JSON using AJAX and XMLHttpResponse

Tags: php, javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I wasn't 100% how to phrase this question. I have a request to a URL similar to

```
example.php?miscData=JSON_FILE_NAME
```

Now JSON_FILE_NAME contains data unique to that file. I've got example.php set-up similar to below

```
    xmlHttpReq.open('GET', strURL, true);
    xmlHttpReq.onload = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
    }
    xmlHttpReq.send();
```

The request file has a function to handle the success of the call and is set up as below

```
function(retData, textStatus, xhr) { }
```

I expected retData would contain the JSON data {"name":"Dominic"} etc... But it doesn't. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does it return instead of JSON data?

Comment: It responds the source of example.php, which is usually empty, or contains <script></script> data dependent on how i've tried to set the page up.

Comment: Can you post your php code, since that's the one giving you problems?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/c7h8V9JK is how it stands right this second.

Comment: So...in your code why are you posting to $setType-$gender.json (line 71)

Comment: There is no POST to anything. I've been trying to write this piece of code for a few hours, and originally had it set-up completely wrong. This is more along the right lines. Inside example.php xmlhttpreq.responseText is right. But from request.php xmlhttpreq.responseText contains the source of example.php and I need it to contain the data contained within $setType-$gender.json

Comment: Which file is example.php and which one is request.php?

Comment: That was example.php. Request.php contains the following js http://pastebin.com/VejXM6rm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side code from http://pastebin.com/c7h8V9JK is responding with an HTML page, not a JSON response.  The code outside of your PHP is nothing but HTML. So naturally, when requesting the page, the server will return the HTML you've put outside of that php script.

Keep in mind, an AJAX request at its most basic is nothing special in terms of sending and receiving data from the server.  Imagine that you have another tab open in your favorite tabbed browser, and that tab is navigating to the URL that your AJAX request is navigating to.  That's what's going on when you make an AJAX request.

If you're trying to get JSON data from example.php, begin by removing all of the HTML from that file and serialize the data that you're trying to get using a JSON serializer.

[encode json using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531965/encode-json-using-php)

Comment: Cheers. Much simpler than what I was trying to do.